# Not all paths return a value error c#

Tags: c#

I am getting error Not all paths return a value. Its a syntax error how to correct it. here is my code. I am writing this code in class.

```
public class Employees
        {
            public String emp_id { get; set; }
            public String emp_name { get; set; }
            public String u_name { get; set; }
            public String pass { get; set; }
            public String mail { get; set; }
            public String address { get; set; }
            public String city { get; set; }
            public String dob { get; set; }
            public String cnic { get; set; }
            public String designation { get; set; }
            public String ph_no { get; set; }
        }
        public class @object
        {
            public static List<Employees> GetAllEmployees()
            {
                List<Employee> listemp = new List<Employee>();
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog=fms; User=root; Pooling=false; Integrated Security = false"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from emp", con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Employees em = new Employees();
                        em.emp_id = dr[0].ToString();
                        em.emp_name = dr[1].ToString();
                        em.u_name = dr[2].ToString();
                        em.pass = dr[3].ToString();
                        em.mail = dr[4].ToString();
                        em.address = dr[5].ToString();
                        em.city = dr[6].ToString();
                        em.dob = dr[7].ToString();
                        em.cnic = dr[8].ToString();
                        em.designation = dr[9].ToString();
                        em.ph_no = dr[10].ToString();
                    }
                    listemp.Add(em);
                }
            }

        }
```

I attached a pic where I am getting this error.[image: The error is highlighted]

Comment: doesn't look like you are returning `listemp`

Comment: You need to return the listemp at the end of the GetAllEmployee method

Comment: move the "listemp.Add(em)" inside the while block

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should return the List **`listemp`** . Also consider moving `listemp.Add(em)` inside while loop, otherwise you wont get a list

```
  public static List<Employees> GetAllEmployees()
            {
                List<Employee> listemp = new List<Employee>();
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog=fms; User=root; Pooling=false; Integrated Security = false"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from emp", con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Employees em = new Employees();
                        em.emp_id = dr[0].ToString();
                        em.emp_name = dr[1].ToString();
                        em.u_name = dr[2].ToString();
                        em.pass = dr[3].ToString();
                        em.mail = dr[4].ToString();
                        em.address = dr[5].ToString();
                        em.city = dr[6].ToString();
                        em.dob = dr[7].ToString();
                        em.cnic = dr[8].ToString();
                        em.designation = dr[9].ToString();
                        em.ph_no = dr[10].ToString();
                        listemp.Add(em);
                    }

                }
               return listemp;
            }
```

Comment: where should I have to return?

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh check the answer

Comment: now this error cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collection.Generic.List` on return statement

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh post the complete error and the code where you call

Comment: Try to remove the static key work before the method GetAllemployee()

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems: `GetAllEmployees()` should return `List<Employees>` and you add `em` to the list outside the `while` scope

```
public static List<Employees> GetAllEmployees()
{
     List<Employee> listemp = new List<Employee>();
     string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog=fms; User=root; Pooling=false; Integrated Security = false"].ConnectionString;
     using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs))
     {
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from emp", con);
         con.Open();
         MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         while (dr.Read())
         {
             Employees em = new Employees();
             em.emp_id = dr[0].ToString();
             em.emp_name = dr[1].ToString();
             em.u_name = dr[2].ToString();
             em.pass = dr[3].ToString();
             em.mail = dr[4].ToString();
             em.address = dr[5].ToString();
             em.city = dr[6].ToString();
             em.dob = dr[7].ToString();
             em.cnic = dr[8].ToString();
             em.designation = dr[9].ToString();
             em.ph_no = dr[10].ToString();

             listemp.Add(em);
         }  
     }

    return listemp;
}
```

Comment: now this error cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collection.Generic.List` on return statement

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh Please post the code calling `GetAllEmployees()`

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh Maybe you try to assign the result of `GetAllEmployees()` to the variable that is not the type of `System.Collection.Generic.List`  and that's why error happens. Please share your code where you invoke `GetAllEmployees()`

Comment: @RamishaFarrukh I can't help if I can't see the code causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the listemp at the end of the method `GetAllEmployee()`

```
return listemp
```

One more thing I noticed, the `listemp.Add(em)` should be inside the while loop. Since your select statement will yield more than one employee. You need to add the employee object each time to the list.